# Macro para copiar varias columnas de datos de un libro a otro

Tags: excel, macros

Tengo la siguiente macro para copiar una columna de un libro a otro libro con un botón, pero me surge la necesidad de no solo copiar una columna si no varias a columnas en diferente posición 
¿Cómo puedo hacer para no solo copiar una columna si no múltiples columnas?

```
Sub copiar_celdas()

Workbooks("ventas.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:a31").Copy

Workbooks("reportesventas.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a8").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. El argumento `"a2:a31"` es lo que estás copiando, y el argumento `"a8"` es el destino. Cambia esos argumentos según tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee los comentarios en el código y ajústalo según tus necesidades

**Código:**

```
Public Sub CopiarColumnas()

    Dim hojaOrigen As Worksheet
    Dim hojaDestino As Worksheet

    ' Definir hojas de origen y destino
    Set hojaOrigen = Workbooks("ventas.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set hojaDestino = Workbooks("reportesventas.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Copiar columnas A - C desde la hoja de origen a la hoja de destino (utilizar referencia de la celda de la primera fila como referencia para empezar a pegar)
    hojaOrigen.Range("A:C").Copy Destination:=hojaDestino.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría saber de qué manera se puede editar el macro para poder copiar en varias ocasiones datos de *hojaOrigen* y que sean pegados en *hojaDestino* pero sin ser reemplazados los datos que ya fueron agregados en anteriores oportunidades. Espero estar explicándome correctamente.

```
Public Sub Facturar()

    Dim hojaOrigen As Worksheet
    Dim hojaDestino As Worksheet

    ' Definir hojas de origen y destino
    Set hojaOrigen = Workbooks("Facturación Final v3.xlsm").Worksheets("Facturación (Varios)")
    Set hojaDestino = Workbooks("Facturación Final v3.xlsm").Worksheets("Reporte de Ventas")

    ' Copiar columnas A - C desde la hoja de origen a la hoja de destino (utilizar referencia de la celda de la primera fila como referencia para empezar a pegar)
    hojaOrigen.Range("G6:G11").Copy Destination:=hojaDestino.Range("B6")

End Sub
```

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/297973)

Answer (score 0):

Otra cosa que necesitaría que el macro realice es copiar un rango adicional de celdas en la misma *hojaDestino*. Probé agregado una segunda línea pero no me funcionó:

```
 hojaOrigen.Range("K6:K11").Copy Destination:=hojaDestino.Range("C6")
```

Por último pero no menos más importante, que se omitan las celdas en blanco al momento de copiar de una hoja a otra.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/297975)